# Why does this function not return or print anything?

Tags: c++

"R3+2-1R2+1-1R2+0-2" is my input, I'm trying to figure out the total number of positive tests (value after + sign) in the string input. I think the function might be entering an infinite loop, but I'm not sure why...

```cpp
int posiTests(string results)
{
    
//concatenator
    
    string resultsc;
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i != results.size(); i++)
    {
        if (results[i] != ' ')
        {
            resultsc += results[i];
        }
    }
    
//positive tests R3+2-1R2+1-1R2+0-2
    
    int j = 1;
    string postests;
    
    while (j <= resultsc.size())
    {
        
        if (isdigit(resultsc[j]))
        {
            j++;
        }
        else if (resultsc[j] == '+')
        {
            while (resultsc[j] != '-')
            {
                if (isdigit(resultsc[j]))
                {
                    postests += resultsc[j];
                }
                else
                {
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    cout << postests;
    
    int value = stoi(postests);
    
    return value;
    
}
```

Comment: `while (resultsc[j] != '-')` may be an infinite loop because `j` is not updated when `isdigit(resultsc[j])` is true.

Comment: Future bug: `while (j <= resultsc.size())` will allow `j` to equal `resultsc.size()`. This is fatal because `j` is used as an index into `resultsc` and the valid indexes of `resultsc` are from 0 to  `resultsc.size() - 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I've revamped the inner loops a bit to make sure `j` gets incremented correctly.

```
    for (size_t j = 0; j < resultsc.size(); ++j)
    {
        if (resultsc[j] != '+')
        {
            continue;
        }

        while (j < resultsc.size() && resultsc[j] != '-')
        {
            if (isdigit(resultsc[j]))
            {
                postests += resultsc[j];
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
```

For your given example, this will print "210". If you wanted "3" instead (2 + 1 + 0), you'd need to call `stoi(postests)` when the while loop finishes.